# How to update previous retained rows in SAS / if condition?

Tags: if-statement, sas, rows, lag, retain

I have a database like this. This corresponds to a single person and I have this type of data for multiple persons.

```
data test;
input date YYMMDD10. real_length min_length;
format date YYMMDD10.;
cards;
2000-02-23 1 7
2000-02-24 12 15
2000-03-07 15 7
2000-03-22 7 15
2000-03-29 13 7
2000-04-11 17 7
2000-04-28 . 7
run;
```

What I am looking for is : if the interval between 2 dates in consecutive lines (real_length) is inferior to a certain length (min_length), I want to replace the date in the next line by the previous date + min_length. So far, this is not a problem and here is the code I used to achieve it:

```
data test2;
set test;
format lagdate min_date YYMMDD10.;
retain lagmin lagdate;
if lag(real_length) < lag(min_length) and lag(real_length) ~= . then min_date = lagdate       + lagmin;
else  min_date = date;
lagdate = min_date;
lagmin = min_length;
run;
```

Which gives :

```
date            min_date       min_length
2000-02-23      2000-02-23         7
2000-02-24      2000-03-01         15
2000-03-07      2000-03-16         7
2000-03-22      2000-03-22         15
...
```

The problem is that now the interval between 2 consecutive dates could become less than the minimal length, e.g. :  2000-03-22 - 2000-03-16 = 6 days < min_length = 7.  And I would like to have 2000-03-23 = 2000-03-16 +  7 (=min_length) instead of 2000-02-22 like this:

```
date            min_date       min_length
2000-02-23      2000-02-23         7
2000-02-24      2000-03-01         15
2000-03-07      2000-03-16         7
2000-03-22      2000-03-23         15
...
```

So I've tried this code, but it does not work... I believe the problem could be in the if condition.

```
data test2;
set test;
format lagdate min_date YYMMDD10.;
retain lagmin lagdate;
if (lag(real_length) < lag(min_length) and lag(real_length) ~= .) or (adjust_length <                  lag(min_length) and adjust_length ~=.) then min_date = lagdate + lagmin;
else  min_date = date;
adjust_length = min_date - lagdate;
lagdate = min_date;
lagmin = min_length;
run;
```

Does anybody see why this isn't working or do you hve another way of doing this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that each time you adjust one date, you have to move all the subsequent dates as well if they're bunched up together. I think you can do this by keeping a running total of how many days you've added on to all the previous rows and then adding on only what's needed after that to get to the min_length between dates:

```
data want;
    set test;
    format t_min_date min_date yymmdd10.;
    if _n_ = 1 then total_adj = 0;
    t_min_date = date + min_length + total_adj;
    min_date = lag1(t_min_date);
    total_adj + max(0,min_length - real_length);
run;
```

Is that what you were aiming for?

N.B. you'll need to replace the `if _n_ = 1` with some `first.id` and `last.id` logic to make this work for multiple individuals in the same dataset.